# error when deployed to azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

When i Publish my project i m getting this error:

> error CS0009: Metadata file
>   'D:\home\site\approot\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights\1.1.1-beta\lib\net45\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll'
>   could not be opened -- Invalid COR20 header signature.

[image]

(I m using asp.net core 1)

Did Someone knows or has experienced the same problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur when you have added a third-party DLL to your application and have not properly added it to your compiler’s project file or references list.

If that's the case this might work:

Open your project in Visual Studio .NET.  Make sure the DLL exists and has been properly added to the reference list.  If you are using VBC or CSC to compile your project, check your application’s CompileApplication.rsp file to make sure the DLL is in the /references list like the other DLLs.

Your DLL may not be compatible with .NET or with .NET’s 32-bit mode.  Ensure that your DLL is .NET compatible.

If your project still won’t compile properly, try switching your application’s compiler selection in Iron Speed Designer’s Application Wizard from 'vbc.exe'  or ‘csc.exe’ to Visual Studio .NET or vice versa.  Using Visual Studio .NET will take longer to build than .NET’s VBC or CSC built-in compilers, but Visual Studio .NET will resolve all of the references properly without having to change your application’s CompileApplication.rsp file.